# $c.length just outputs a ton of one's, not the length

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to learn some PowerShell, and was playing around trying to make the following script (to take all Starttime values from Get-Process and save them in a form excluding the Time part of the DateTime Object.)

```
    $a=( Get-Process |Where-Object ProcessName -NotMatch 'Idle' | Select-Object -property starttime);

 #I think Select-Object part may not be necessary, but left in as that's how 
 #I've coded it

 $b= $a.starttime; 

$c=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[DateTime];

$count=0; @(0..($b.length-1)).foreach({ Write-Host $count,$b[$_].ToShortDateString(); $c.add($b[$_].ToShortDateString()); $count++ })
```

And *I think* it does what I intended it to do. Calling `$b[j]-$c[j]` produces only values of Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds. However, when I call the lengths, I get the following

```
$b.length
```

> 175

```
$c.length
```

> 1

> 1

> 1

> etc.,

So why is this? I'm not too versed in powershell (been playing with it for about a week), and I feel as though `$c.length` should spit out the same value as `$b.length`? What have I done in error?

Comment: The ```System.Collections.Generic.List`1``` type doesn't have a `Length` property. Use `Count` instead

Comment: Oof, I figured it would've thrown an error if that was the case, I didn't even notice. Is there a way to double check what properties certain things have? as I tried Get-member on $b and that one is also a DateTime object, is that because it's not technically a System.Collections.Generic.List ? Or is there another reason?

Comment: The pipeline unravels enumerable objects by default, so you'd want to do `Get-Member -InputObject $c`, rather than `$c |Get-Member` :)

Comment: Ahh Yes, that makes sense. Pipe sends stuff one by one, I knew that (although apparently I didn't know it well xD ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the solution to this problem is straight-forward - use `Count` to obtain the total count of items in the list:

```
$c.Count
```

---

PowerShell, since version 4.0, supports something called "property enumeration", which means that when you reference a property name on an enumerable object (like a `List[Datetime]` for example) with the `.` member resolution operator, and the property doesn't exist on the referenced object, PowerShell will attempt to resolve that property name against the items *contained* in the enumerable object.

The generic `List[]` type doesn't have a `Length` property, hence the 175 individual results :)